# Set multiple zimbraDNSCHeckHostname values on Zimbra OSE 8.0.7

Tags: ubuntu, zimbra

On Zimbra OSE 8.0.7 on Ubuntu 12.04 a configuration value: `zimbraDNSCHeckHostname` correspond to the  inbound SMTP server in front of Zimbra (often anti spam relay).
In my case I have two antispam relay with name:

```
relay.domain.com
relayfailover.domain.com
```

I need to setup those two value in that field while it can't contain multiple value.

How it's possible ? is it a limitation of the free version or maybe I misunderstood the purpose of that field ?

I already try to set it from CLI using :

```
zmprov mcf zimbraDNSCheckHostname 'relay.domain.com;relayfailover.domain.com'
zmprov mcf zimbraDNSCheckHostname '*.domain.com'
```

thought it works it never applyed correctly and I can't receive mail.

Answer (score 0):

if it's failover, you just set up the first, and in case of failover, change the record. Can be scripted with some sort of simple monitoring script.

if you need it to load balance between the two, just give them a common dns name and use dns-round-robin